# How can I prevent basement slab moisture from causing mold in flooring?

Tags: concrete, flooring, floor, mold, vapor-barrier

I live in a residential community built in the late 80s. I believe no vapor barrier was put under the concrete because when we switched from carpet to wood floors mold starting coming through after a year. We ripped up the new floors and polished the concrete to give it a couple years to dry out as well as redid the outside fixing the grading and drainage around the outside of the house. Its been about 4 years now and moisture is STILL coming up through the concrete as evidence by the white mineral deposits under our rugs and dark spots where there are no rugs. Also with a moisture reader. I would love to put floors back down but how do I ensure that this doesn't happen again? Are there any products or new technology that would allow me to put something on the concrete and then put floors back down without the mold issue?

Comment: Do you have any sump pump or interior sub-floor drainage to keep the water level below your floor?

Comment: Sounds like you have a fairly high water table.  Perhaps not high enough to come through the walls, but enough to keep your slab damp.